# In R, how to split/subset a data frame by factors in more than one column?

Tags: r

My data looks like :

```
ID   Test Type       Subject  Marks
1    Unit test 1     English   85
2    Unit test 1     English   75
3    Unit test 1     English   78
1    Unit test 2     English   85
2    Unit test 2     English   75
3    Unit test 2     English   78
1    Unit test 1     Maths     78
2    Unit test 1     Maths     79
3    Unit test 1     Maths     98
1    Unit test 2     Maths     95
2    Unit test 2     Maths     98
3    Unit test 2     Maths     88
```

I want to split the data by "Test Type" and "Subject".What function should I use?
My desired result is :

```
data frame 1:
    ID   Test Type       Subject  Marks
    1    Unit test 1     English   85
    2    Unit test 1     English   75
    3    Unit test 1     English   78

data frame 2:
    ID   Test Type       Subject  Marks
    1    Unit test 2     English   85
    2    Unit test 2     English   75
    3    Unit test 2     English   78

data frame 3 :
    ID   Test Type       Subject  Marks
    1    Unit test 1     Maths     78
    2    Unit test 1     Maths     79
    3    Unit test 1     Maths     98

data frame 4:
    ID   Test Type       Subject  Marks
    1    Unit test 2     Maths     95
    2    Unit test 2     Maths     98
    3    Unit test 2     Maths     88
```

Comment: Probably `split()`, but please show the desired result

Comment: Richard's answer will get you what you want.  But if you ever have to do aggregation on your grouped data frames, you should consider using `ddply`.

Comment: @richard scriven

As per the split function's protype:
split(x, f, drop = FALSE, ...)

Can't I use split(data,data[,c("Test Type","Subject")]) to split the data on the basis of "Test Type" and "Subject" ?

Comment: No, did you try it?  You have to select a column for splitting.  Either of the answers below would work well

Comment: You almost surely want `dplyr` not `split`, like @TimBiegeleisen said, since you will be doing some processing on each group, then either merging or summarizing the result back to a dataframe or summary statistics. `dplyr` is a truly beautiful and scalable paradigm for split-apply-combine, please check it out. It will solve all your problems :)

Comment: @smci Just restored my answer...thanks for the support!

Comment: There's a lot of assumption happening in the comments.  The question simply asks how to split the data :)  Splitting data into a list is not super-easy for the novice dplyr user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple solution is to use `by`:

```
list.df <- by(df, INDICES =  list(df$Test.Type, df$Subject), FUN = data.frame)
```

**Results**

```
> list.df
: Unit test 1
: English
  ID   Test.Type Subject Marks
1  1 Unit test 1 English    85
2  2 Unit test 1 English    75
3  3 Unit test 1 English    78
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
: Unit test 2
: English
  ID   Test.Type Subject Marks
4  1 Unit test 2 English    85
5  2 Unit test 2 English    75
6  3 Unit test 2 English    78
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
: Unit test 1
: Maths
  ID   Test.Type Subject Marks
7  1 Unit test 1   Maths    78
8  2 Unit test 1   Maths    79
9  3 Unit test 1   Maths    98
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
: Unit test 2
: Maths
   ID   Test.Type Subject Marks
10  1 Unit test 2   Maths    95
11  2 Unit test 2   Maths    98
12  3 Unit test 2   Maths    88
```

You can then access each individual dataframe by using `list.df[[1]]` through `list.df[[4]]`.

(And thx to Richard Scriven for `dput`ing the data in his answer.)

Comment: @user2745366 And don't forget to accept (green checkmark) the answer you opted for, whichever it was...

Answer (score 4):

You could use `split()` (thanks to DrDom for the improvement).

```
split(df, list(df$Test.Type, df$Subject))
# $`Unit test 1.English`
#   ID   Test.Type Subject Marks
# 1  1 Unit test 1 English    85
# 2  2 Unit test 1 English    75
# 3  3 Unit test 1 English    78
# 
# $`Unit test 2.English`
#   ID   Test.Type Subject Marks
# 4  1 Unit test 2 English    85
# 5  2 Unit test 2 English    75
# 6  3 Unit test 2 English    78
# 
# $`Unit test 1.Maths`
#   ID   Test.Type Subject Marks
# 7  1 Unit test 1   Maths    78
# 8  2 Unit test 1   Maths    79
# 9  3 Unit test 1   Maths    98
# 
# $`Unit test 2.Maths`
#    ID   Test.Type Subject Marks
# 10  1 Unit test 2   Maths    95
# 11  2 Unit test 2   Maths    98
# 12  3 Unit test 2   Maths    88
```

where `df` is the original data.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), Test.Type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Unit test 1", "Unit test 2"), class = "factor"),
    Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("English", "Maths"), class = "factor"), 
    Marks = c(85L, 75L, 78L, 85L, 75L, 78L, 78L, 79L, 98L, 95L, 
    98L, 88L)), .Names = c("ID", "Test.Type", "Subject", "Marks"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: `split(df, list(df[,2], df[,3]))` call will be simplier and will return the same output.

Comment: Oh wow, I never knew you could use a list in the split.  Thanks @DrDom, very nice.  Learn something new every day!

Comment: Like in `aggregate` you may use lists for subsetting.

Comment: Using a list in split is indeed insane!

Comment: Another variation for fun: `split(df, do.call(paste0, df[2:3]))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is code which would compute the average Mark for each Test Type/Subject combination:

```
# df($testtype, $subject)

> ddply(df, .(testtype, subject), summarize, avgmark = round(mean(marks), 0))
```

**Result:**

```
     testtype subject avgmark
1 Unit Test 1 English      79
2 Unit Test 1   Maths      85
3 Unit Test 2 English      79
4 Unit Test 2   Maths      94
```

The `ddply` function will compute an `avgmark` for each group and return a data frame result.  You can replace `avgmark` with whatever aggregate function you want.  You can also add more aggregate functions after `avgmark`.  Have a look at this article for more information.